# Retrieve data from post webhook using React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, go, react-redux

So this is a more general question and I did not know who to turn to. I have configured a webhook using from a live streaming third party platform I am using. I did this using Golang and tested my webhook I am getting the POST data how I want. Now the problem is how do you get this data back on the front end. I have looked into setting up websockets and server side events. They both don't make too much sense to me as I see the work on the front end should be pretty straightforward. I don't think I should have to configure another endpoint to get the webhook data and it doesn't listen to the webhook async anyway so I don't think that will work. Any help please...

Comment: In general, you don't hook into a webhook directly, it's designed to just run in response to something independent of everything else. So when you find yourself trying to do this, there's no real general solution, it depends on your specific use case. So it depends on what the webhook is doing, what the POST is doing, what the POST response signifies, how data is being handled/stored in this use case, what your frontend is trying to do, etc..

Comment: So the POST response is a JSON object that returns if a stream is active or not. So I need that info to update the UI on the frontend to show a video or not.